# Read gmail with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, email

Im trying to read mails from a gmail apps account by using Zend Framework. I've just transfered the Zend Framework dir to my server (path: /Zend/library/).

How do I load the Zend Framework and the Mail module? And how do I further read the mail?

I've tried the following with no results:

```
$path = 'Zend/library/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

I believe the syntax for reading the inbox is something like:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array('host' => 'imap.gmail.com', 'user' => "name@domain.com", 'password' => "mypassword", 'ssl' => 'SSL'));
```

**EDIT**

The following code works:

```
$path = 'Zend/library/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array('host'     => 'imap.gmail.com',
                                         'user'     => 'mail@domain.com',
                                         'password' => 'password',
                                         'ssl'      => 'SSL'));
echo $mail->countMessages();`
```

... but when i try to echo unread emails:

```
echo "Unread mails:\n";
foreach ($mail as $message) {
    if ($message->hasFlag(Zend_Mail_Storage::FLAG_SEEN)) {
        continue;
    }
    // mark recent/new mails
    if ($message->hasFlag(Zend_Mail_Storage::FLAG_RECENT)) {
        echo '! ';
    } else {
        echo '  ';
    }
    echo $message->subject . "\n";
}
```

I get the following message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Storage_Exception' with message 'cannot login, user or password wrong' in /var/www/zvinx.dk/test/Zend/library/Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php:279 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/zvinx.dk/test/gmail.php(11): Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap->__construct(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/zvinx.dk/test/Zend/library/Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php on line 279
```

It says the username or password is wrong, which is weird cause I didnt change it from when it was working... How come this error occur?

Comment: hmm for me error message pretty obvious `cannot login, user or password wrong`

Comment: Indeed - but it works fine when I just echo the count of the messages but not when trying to echo the unread messages.. it doesnt make any sense to me at least..

Comment: Try to add port I guess port is `995`

Comment: have you enabled imap on gmail?

Comment: Yep.. I dont understand how its possible to get the count of my emails in my inbox, but when I try to echo the messages, it says the login failed

Answer (score 2):

the gmail settings are a little tricky. try:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array('host'     => 'imap.gmail.com',
                                         'user'     => 'mail@domain.com',
                                         'port'     => '993',
                                         'password' => 'password',
                                         'ssl'      => 'tls',
                                         'auth'     => 'login'
                                          ));
```

NOTE: the gmail are using the SSL/TLS protocol which apparently is different than the standard SSL.

Comment: @Greg Forbes  I am getting " cannot connect to host; error = Connection timed out (errno = 110 )" error. What should I do

Answer (score 1):

You really don't think that you can start using Zend Framework without reading/learning about the basics of the framework? At least take a look at the [quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) on how to use the framework with the autoloading features and then dive into the [Zend_Mail documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html), more specifically the part that says "[Reading Mail Messages](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html)"

Comment: Thx for the links - I've almost got it working now. I've updated the question with the new problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are the login setting i use to read emails via IMAP and dump attached files

```
public function imapAction()
{
    $config = array('host'=> 'imap.gmail.com', 
        'user' => 'xx',
        'password' => 'xx',
        'ssl' => 'SSL',
        'port' => 993);//995 pop, imap 993

    $mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($config);
    $maxMessage = $mail->countMessages();
    $this->logger->info($maxMessage);

    for ($i = $maxMessage; $i <= $maxMessage; $i++)
    {
        $message = $mail->getMessage($i);
        $this->logger->info($i.'Mail from '.$message->from.':'.$message->subject);

        if($message->isMultipart())
        {
            $this->logger->info("has attachments");
            $part = $message->getPart(2);

            $cnt_typ = explode(";" , $part->contentType);
            $name    = explode("=",$cnt_typ[1]);
            $filename   = $name[1];//It is the file name of the attachement in browser
            //This for avoiding " from the file name when sent from yahoomail
            $filename   = str_replace('"'," ",$filename);
            $this->logger->info($filename);

            $attachment = base64_decode($part->getContent());
            $fhandle = fopen($filename, 'w');
            fwrite($fhandle, $attachment);
            fclose($fhandle);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this instruction has helped me.

1. Quit all mail clients that are accessing the affected Gmail account. This means the Mail app on the iPhone and any other place you are accessing your Gmail from such as a computer.
2. Open browser and navigate to this page: http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
3. Enter your full Gmail address, password and type the characters you see in the picture. Touch the unlock button to verify your account.
4. Try to read mails from a gmail apps account by using Zend Framework. Your Gmail access should be restored.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this error and you are 100% sure about the password you provided it might come from the 2 factor authentication you set on your google account.

[Google help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en) gives indications on what to do in this case. I manage to get access to my account by generating an [AppPassword](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) in my case